# HTML/CSS Login page issues with styling in IE not workng

Tags: html, css

i have a login page that seems to work fine in chrome, chrome(windows), safari and firefox but when i test it in IE. There seems to be a huge break between the login boxes and the 'forgot username or password' link. I have no idea as to why this is, could someone please help me resolve this issue?

HTML:

```
<body id="loginpage">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="maintable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="container">
                <div id="login_header">
                    <a href="#" id="homelink"></a>
                    <h1><b>TEST Vario Press CMS Demo</b></h1>
                    <div id="logo"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="content">
                    <!-- Begin Content -->
                    <div id="dialog">
                        <h2>Client Login</h2>
                        <div class="content">
                            <form action="#" name="login" id="login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" autocomplete="off" _lpchecked="1">
                                <div id="login_form">
                                    <div class="error"></div>
                                    Please enter your username and password
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="username_field"><label>Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" onkeypress="return checkenter(event)"></li>
                                        <li id="password_field"><label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" value="" onkeypress="return checkenter(event)"></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ok_button" title="Login" onclick="login.submit()">
                                    <a href="#">GO</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button" id="submit_button">
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Login">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <div id="login_links">
                                <div class="forgot">
                                    <a href="#">Forgot username or password?</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="register">
                                    <a href="#">Register</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#login_header h1, #login_header #logo, #header h1 b {
display:none;
}

#dialog {
width:520px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
color:#FFF;

}

#login_form {
background-color:#808080;
padding:18px;
padding-bottom:42px;
text-align:center;

}

#dialog, #dialog .error {
color:#FFF;
}

#dialog h2 {
background-color: #808080;
background-image: url("../imgs/table_bg.gif");
color:#fff;
padding:9px;
font-size:20px;
text-align:left;
margin:0px;
}

#dialog .content {
padding:0;
list-style: none;
}

#dialog .ok_button {
display:none;
}

#dialog #submit_button input {
padding:7px 5px;
text-align: center;
}

#dialog .clear {
display:none;
}

.highlight_field {
background-color:#f57921;
}

#forgot h3 {
text-align:center;
}

#my_details {
width:auto;
}

#loginpage #my_details {
width:400px;
}

#forgot h3 {
font-size: 12px;
}

#login ul {
margin-left:8px;
list-style: none;

}

#login ul input{
width: 350px;
height: 25px;
    padding-left: 10px;
background-color: #FFF;
border: none;
border-width: 0px;
position: relative;
left: -20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;    
    border-radius: 5px;
    behavior : url(../js/PIE.htc);

    /*
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;*/
}

#login #submit_button {
display:block;
position:relative;
top:-48px;
right:10px;
}

#login_links {
margin-top:0;
text-align:left;
}

#login_links .forgot {
float:none;
display:block;
}

#login_links .register, #login_links .whyregister {
display: none;
}

#login_links .forgot a {
display:block;
width:484px;
color:#FFF;
background-color:#808080;
padding:18px;
font-weight:normal;
text-decoration: none;

}


#login_links .forgot a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;

}

#login label {
width:6em;
display: block;
text-align: left;
/*float: left;*/
line-height: 25px;
margin-left: 22px;

}


#ie6 #login_form {
margin-bottom:-47px;
}

#ie6 #submit_button {
position:relative;
top:-4px;
}

#page_mydetails .recordset {
width:48%;
}

.recordset h4 {
font-size:11px;
background-image:url(../imgs/table_bg.gif);
background-color:#535c66;
color:#fff;
border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF;
padding:9px;
}


#loginpage #content {
padding-top:18px;

}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MpEX2/

Comment: looks fine in ie9 which version of ie ur checking into.....

Comment: You HTML tags a mismatched. Use your editor to format your code and you'll see this. JSFiddle even warns about this by coloring on of the `</div>` red. Overall your HTML is very unreadable, I don't know if that's SO formatting or if you write it like that. Try running your HTML through this validator. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: The cap is present in latest Chrome runing under OSX as well by the way. It's not a rendering problem, your HTML is just not valid.

Comment: @Hugo T The HTML was pre-written and i am just modifying everything

Comment: @iNeed_anAnswer as I said try removing all indentation and manually indent it. The HTML is totally unreadable so it's pretty much impossible to figure out what's wrong with the HTML in this condition.

Comment: http://www.dirtymarkup.com/ Please include all the closing tags.

Comment: reedited the code with all closing tags

Comment: @iNeed_anAnswer Clean your code, Try removing unwanted spaces and tabs. This problem is familiar with IE

Comment: Hi try using beautifier to clean ur code and save time ..http://ctrlq.org/beautifier/

Comment: @HugoT With regards to JSFiddle's highlighting of errors: that doesn't count. JSFiddle doesn't know that `<input>` needs no end tag.

Comment: @iNeed_anAnswer Is the problem solved now?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it so it looks good in Chrome. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MpEX2/11/).

I moved everything inside the login_form div and removed any position: relative; stuff from the CSS. I have no idea why anything was using position: relative; as it just screwed up the layout.

Try not to over us position: relative and other positioning values except for static which is the default. Another age old advice is *don't use tables for layout*.

**HTML:**

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="maintable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="container">

                <div id="login_header">
                    <a href="#" id="homelink"></a>
                    <h1><b>TEST Vario Press CMS Demo</b></h1>
                    <div id="logo"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="content">
                    <!-- Begin Content -->

                    <div id="dialog">
                        <h2>Client Login</h2>

                        <div class="content">
                            <form action="#" name="login" id="login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" autocomplete="off" _lpchecked="1">
                                <div id="login_form">

                                    <div class="error"></div>

                                    Please enter your username and password
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="username_field">
                                            <label>Username:</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" onkeypress="return checkenter(event)">
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="password_field">
                                            <label>Password:</label>
                                            <input type="password" name="password" value="" onkeypress="return checkenter(event)">
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="ok_button" title="Login" onclick="login.submit()">
                                        <a href="#">GO</a>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="button" id="submit_button">
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Login">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </form>
                            <div id="login_links">
                                <div class="forgot">
                                    <a href="#">Forgot username or password?</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="register">
                                    <a href="#">Register</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
#login_header h1, #login_header #logo, #header h1 b {
    display:none;
}

#dialog {
    width:520px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;

}

#login_form {
    background-color:#808080;
    padding:18px;
    padding-bottom:42px;
    text-align:center;

}

#dialog, #dialog .error {
    color:#FFF;
}

#dialog h2 {
    background-color: #808080;
    background-image: url("../imgs/table_bg.gif");
    color:#fff;
    padding:9px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0px;
}

#dialog .content {
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
}

#dialog .ok_button {
    display:none;
}

#dialog #submit_button input {
    padding:7px 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

#dialog .clear {
    display:none;
}

.search_button {
    background-image:url(../imgs/nav_ok.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left -2px;
    width:26px;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-right:12px;
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.highlight_field {
    background-color:#f57921;
}

#forgot h3 {
    text-align:center;
}



#my_details {
    width:auto;
}

#loginpage #my_details {
    width:400px;
}

#forgot h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
}

#login ul {
    margin-left:8px;
    list-style: none;

}

#login ul input{
    width: 350px;
    height: 25px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: none;
    border-width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    behavior : url(../js/PIE.htc);

    /*
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;*/
}

#login_links {
    margin-top:0;
    text-align:left;
}

#login_links .forgot {
    float:none;
    display:block;
}

#login_links .register, #login_links .whyregister {
    display: none;
}

#login_links .forgot a {
    display:block;
    width:484px;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#808080;
    padding:18px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration: none;

}


#login_links .forgot a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;

}

#login label {
    width:6em;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    /*float: left;*/
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-left: 22px;

}

#page_mydetails .recordset {
    width:48%;
}

.recordset h4 {
    font-size:11px;
    background-image:url(../imgs/table_bg.gif);
    background-color:#535c66;
    color:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding:9px;
}

.highlight {
    background-color:#f7b100;
    color:#000;
}

.highlight a, .highlight a:visited {
    color:#000;
}

#nav a:hover, #nav .active a {
    color:#f7b100;
}

#loginpage #content {
    padding-top:18px;

}
```